# Set Currently Selected Cells as the Range to Process

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I am building an Excel Addin using Visual Studio and translating my Excel VBA code to VB.Net code.

I cannot figure out how to run a macro via the addin on cells which are selected in Excel.

This code executes on cell A1. How can I change it to work on all selected cells?

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Ribbon1

    Private Sub Ribbon1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As RibbonUIEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnFontToggle_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles BtnFontToggle.Click

            Dim ActiveWorksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet =
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

            Dim Worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet =
            Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(ActiveWorksheet)

        Dim CurrentColor
        Dim Selection As Excel.Range = Worksheet.Range("A1")

'******* Instead of selecting cell A1, I want the code to select all active cells (those that are currently highlighted)*****

        'What is the current font color?
        CurrentColor = Selection.Font.ColorIndex

        'Change font color based on current font color
        'Order Black, Blue, Green, Red
        If CurrentColor = 1 Then
            Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Else
            If CurrentColor = 5 Then
                Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 10
            Else
                If CurrentColor = 10 Then
                    Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    If CurrentColor = 3 Then
                        Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Else
                        Selection.Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Application.Selection Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-selection-property-excel) to determine if an Excel.Range is currently selected and if so, retrieve it.  Note that the current selection may be some other object like a ChartArea.  The Selection Property returns type `Object`, so use `TryCast` to attempt conversion to an `Excel.Range`.  If the conversion fails, `TryCast` returns `Nothing`.

```
Dim Selection As Excel.Range = TryCast(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection, Excel.Range)
If Selection IsNot Nothing Then
   ' you retrieved a Range object
End If
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much TnTinMn and for the explanation.